# Clojure way to create sublists representing edges of larger list

Tags: graph, clojure, edges

Given this:

```
["a" "bunch" "of" "words"]
```

I'd like a function that produces:

```
[["a" "bunch"] ["a" "of"] ["a" "words"]
 ["bunch" "of"] ["bunch" "words"]
 ["of" "words"]]
```

I'm basically trying to enumerate the edges of the words in the first vector.

Something like this is close:

```
(for [i lst, j (rest lst) :when (not= i j)] (conj [] i j))
```

But of course it backtracks.  In other words, I end up with ["words" "bunch"] ["words" of"] etc when they were already captured in the first pass.

Perhaps this needs to be done manually with loop recur?  But first I thought to check if I'm missing something obvious or a nice core function that already exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
(def lst ["a" "bunch" "of" "words"])

(let [cnt (count lst) r (range cnt)]
  (for [a r b r :when (< a b)]
    [(lst a) (lst b)]))


;=> (["a" "bunch"] ["a" "of"] ["a" "words"] ["bunch" "of"] ["bunch" "words"] ["of" "words"])
```

This seems to be the same as printing upper triangle of 4x4 matrix.

If you want the result to be vector, then

```
(apply vector 
       (let [cnt (count lst) r (range cnt)]
         (for [a r b r :when (< a b)]
           [(lst a) (lst b)])))
```

Comment: I get an error LazySeq cannot be cast to IFn.  And I'm not following what the (w a) (w b) is.  What is the w identifier?

Comment: @Scott `w` should be changed to `lst`. I updated the answer. I'm sorry for the typo. `(lst a)` means `a`-th element of `lst`. Since vector also works as a function, you don't have to use `nth` in this case. `(lst a)` and `(nth lst a)` are effectively the same.

Comment: You can also use: `(for [b r a (range b)] [(lst a) (lst b)])`.

Answer (score 1):

A simple, recursive way:

```
(defn edges [[f & r]]
  (when f (concat (map #(do [f %]) r) (edges r))))
```